# Nodejs, npm, orm: how to insert multi row, only if it not exists

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, npm

I am trying to insert a row into mysql-database via [orm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/orm).

But only if the row don´t exists in db.

I has try this code below.

```
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    req.models.Links.one({ 
        url: links[i].href 
    }, function(err, Links){ 
        if(!err) {
            console.log('Link fund! -->links['+i+'].href-->'+JSON.stringify(links[i]));
            req.models.Links.create({ 
                createat: new Date(),
                title: links[i].title,
                url: links[i].href
            }, function(err, items){
                if(err) console.error(err);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I use [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) to build the app.

See code on: [github.com](https://github.com/voidcode/tinysearch/blob/master/app.js#L149).

The problems is var **i** do not increment([see line-157](https://github.com/voidcode/tinysearch/blob/master/app.js#L157)).

Comment: How do you know `i` is not incrementing? Are you logging it somewhere?

Comment: Yes data from the debugger,..

Comment: Well, I didn't read all the code in the link you posted, but when you have to call asynchronous functions in a loop, do not use regular `for` loops: use modules like [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async), that handles those scenarios in a pretty straightforward way.